# What is Android activity and package for Calendar App for HTC, Motorola and Sony?

Tags: android, class, android-activity, calendar, package

What is Android activity and package for Calendar App for HTC, Motorola and Sony?

I figured out this for Samsung device

- Package : com.android.calendar
- Class : com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity

Anyone could share? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **try to avoid** calling an application through an explicit intent. The reason for this is because a user may have multiple calendar applications on their device, you should be using a normal intent with a specific action relevant to what you're trying to use.